# No file available under C:\Users\Prabodh\.m2\repository after installing Apache Maven

Tags: maven

I have installed Maven (latest version available in Internet) in my system. I am using windows 7. In command prompt, the version is showing correctly (through mvn -version command); but there is no file is available in C:\Users\Prabodh.m2\repository.... I am not sure why this problem is occurring...

Please let me know what are the files should be present there in a typical/standard installation; and what is the possible reason I am not being able to access them...

Comment: which file you are expecting settings.xml ??

Comment: No file will be there until you run maven or put a file there.

Comment: Nothing should be there by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `settings.xml` then here is the answer -

The settings file is never created automatically, you must create it yourself, whether you use embedded or "real" maven.

Create it at the following location `<your home folder>/.m2/settings.xml` e.g. in your case `C:\Users\Prabodh\.m2\settings.xml`

And at the location `C:\Users\Prabodh\.m2\repository` maven will install all the jars from the Maven Central Repo when you build the project for first time.

For more I would highly recommend you to go through this [Maven Specs for Settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maven starts as an empty plugin execution framework. So as long as Maven hasn't done a thing, your local repository will stay empty.

Try `mvn help:help` on the commandline (any directory will do). This way you will get the help description of the maven-help plugin. Be warned, the first time it'll download quite a lot. But if you execute `mvn help:help` for a second time, all its required code is already available in your local repository, so it'll display the help very fast.